# Domain A to Domain B, CNAME MAPPING

Tags: subdomain, cname-record

I have an account with NING where I have a social network setup as "networkname.ning.com" and I have a domain from netfirms www.example..com. My problem is that the ning network is telling me that I need to do this step [in this KB](http://web.archive.org/web/20120413201449/http://www.ning.com/help/cgi-bin/ning.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=2920).

What I really need to understand is how to do this on netfirms where all my options are this

[image]

Any help is REALLY appreciated and if someone can explain to me what exactly CNAME is and A name is that would be great (in newbie terms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNAME is just an alias to another domain. When you type `www.somedomain.com` it will actual get redirected to `networkname.ning.com`.

an A record is the actual DNS entry that maps a domain name to a specific IP address. For example, if your web server has a static IP as `212.20.10.10` and you wish to point the domain `www.somedomain.com` to this IP address, you use an A record.

Just put `networkname.ning.com` in the hostname box on netfirms and check it out.

Comment: Hmm thats what i did but it doesnt seem to be working :( the thing is you are required to put in a subdomain, so i entered "www" into the subdomain. Its been over 14hrs and no change. I think i might have to do the A name. Do you know how long i should expect changes to occur? Thanks

Comment: DNS change propagation can even take 24 hours but usually happens fast. It all depends on how long the TTL (time to live) value for the DNS record has been set. It helps to clear your local DNS cache just in case the old DNS entries are saved there. On Windows, from the command line, type IFCONFIG /FLUSHDNS to clear the cache. You could also close your browser after this and start again to avoid browser caching the old dns entries.